# Computing probability of extracting AT LEAST n balls from a urn

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I cannot figure out how to model the probability computation in the following scenario.

I have an urn with 31 balls, of which 21 are red and 10 are black. If I extract 10 balls from the urn, what is the probability that AT LEAST 6 are black?

(edit: it's a bulk extraction, so no replacement or order matter)

I am more interested in how to use binomial formulas than in the numeric result; thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Preassuming that this is done without replacement:$$\sum_{n=6}^{10}p_n$$where: $$p_n=\frac{\binom{10}n\binom{21}{10-n}}{\binom{31}{10}}$$is the probability that *exactly* $n$ are black.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :)

Comment: This is the exact way to do it. If it concerns large numbers then you will have to make use of approximation. It depends on the context which is most suitable. Actually you might add (without taking away your original question) what you are really after in an edit of your question.

Comment: Thanks I managed to compute it with wolfram alpha :)

Comment: @EdoardoReggiori There are some formulas to make large combinatorial sums easier.